# Laravel get logged in user in Observer when event is triggered from queued job

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but if it is it will save me lots of duplicate code.  I have many queued jobs that handle importing csv data.  I need to track the changes that have been made in these imports and who made the changes.  I implemented [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) for each model and I can log the changes but I can't get the user that imported the data since the changes take place in a queued job.  The job itself is aware of the user since I am passing the user to the job, but I can't figure out how to pass the user to the observer.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

I'm using the [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/) package to handle the imports, and this package also integrates queuing the jobs.  Here's the code from the import job:

```php
class QueuedImport implements ToCollection, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    use Importable;

    private $user;
    private $client;

    public function __construct($user, $client)
    {
        $this->user = $user; // this is the logged in user
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        //each row updates a model, which triggers the update event in the observer
        $this->importRows($rows, $this->client, $this->user);

    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

    //....
}
```

And here's the observer's update event:

```php
public function updated(MyModel $model)
    {
        $original = $model->getOriginal();
        $user = auth()->user();
        foreach ($model->getChanges() as $key => $value) {
            \App\History::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id ?? null,
                'model_id' => $model->id,
                'field' => $key,
                'old_value' => $original[$key],
                'new_value' => $value
            ]);
        }
    }
```

When I update the model and it's not in a queued job, the user saves fine.  I understand that queued jobs are not aware of the authenticated user, but there must be some way to get the user into the observer.

I realize I could just track the change in the Job, but I have many places this model could be updated, and I don't want to worry about finding all the different spots it may be updated.  Can this be done, and how?

Answer (score 0):

I am not super happy with this solution, but maybe this is gonna work.

You might want to implement the [laravel excel events](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/extending.html#events) with the `Auth` facade.

```php
use Auth;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;

class QueuedImport implements ToCollection, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue, withEvents
{
    use Importable;

    private $user;
    private $client;

    public function __construct($user, $client)
    {
        $this->user = $user; // this is the logged in user
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        //each row updates a model, which triggers the update event in the observer
        $this->importRows($rows, $this->client, $this->user);

    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

    public function beforeImport()
    {
        Auth::loginUsingId($this->user->id);
    }

    public function afterImport()
    {
        Auth::logout();
    }

    //....
}
```

Comment: I was hopeful that this would work, but it looks like the observer still thinks there is no user authenticated.  I'm not quite sure what's going on, I can see the logged in user in the `beforeImport` function, but I can't in the `collection` method.  I guess that's why the observer still can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with was not ideal, but I couldn't think of another way to do it.  I ended up adding a column to each of the tables I am observing, `updated_by`.  So when the model is updated, I populate that field with the currently logged in user.  Then I have access to that field in the observer through the model.  So this is what I have now in the observer:

```php
public function updated(MyModel $model)
    {
        $original = $model->getOriginal();
        $user = $model->created_by; // <--- this is the new field I added
        foreach ($model->getChanges() as $key => $value) {
            \App\History::create([
                'user_id' => $user,
                'model_id' => $model->id,
                'field' => $key,
                'old_value' => $original[$key],
                'new_value' => $value
            ]);
        }
    }
```